# How do I efficiently calculate the total sum with respect to a changing v in a square root?

Tags: summation, sums-of-squares

How do I efficiently calculate the total sum with respect to a changing
$\space v \space\space $in a square root
$\sqrt{\dfrac {\hbar{((v)/(6.25E34))}}{4G}}r\space\large{?}$

The sum is based on the variable
$\space "v"\space $ in the following expression which changes in increments of $\space 1\space $ with $\space vi=1\space \text{ to }\space vf=6.25E34.\quad$ Everything else in the expression is a constant.

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{\hbar{((1)/(6.25E34))}}{4G}}r 
\\+ 
\sqrt{\frac{\hbar{((2)/(6.25E34))}}{4G}}r 
\\+ 
\sqrt{\frac{\hbar{((3)/(6.25E34))}}{4G}}r 
+\\ \cdots+ 
\sqrt{\frac{\hbar{((6.25E34)/(6.25E34))}}{4G}} r
 \\= \text{total}
\end{equation}

To help give a visual aid the expression would operate as depicted here in the following illustration.  ~ thank you.

[image]

Comment: Replace your sum with an integral.  You can factor out all the constants and be left with $\int_1^{v_f}\sqrt v dv$

Comment: won't an integral create the total sum of infinitesimals? If so, doesn't that lead to an infinity?

Comment: Your sum corresponds to the Riemann sum with divisions of width $1$.  The error between the rectangles of the Riemann sum and the true integral is very small.  You can assess it by changing the lower limit from $1$ to $0$ and subtracting $1$ from the upper limit.  That changes the Riemann sum from the low value in each interval to the high value.

Comment: Math really isn't my strong suit, can you tell me why an integral would work and a summation would not?

Comment: We don't have a nice closed form for the sum of $\sqrt n$ like we do for $n, n^2$ and so on.  We do have a nice closed form for the integral, which is just $\frac 23n^{3/2}$

Comment: So are you suggesting something like this? $r\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{4G}}
*\frac 23(({v_f}^{\frac 32})-({v_i}^{\frac 32}))$

Comment: You seem to have lost the division by $6.25E34$ but the rest looks right.  I didn't check it carefully.

Comment: I manually added in the division when I did the calculation making $v_f=6.25E34/6.25E34$ and $v_i=1/6.25E34$. However, there is a problem. When using $\frac 23(({v_f}^{\frac 32})-({v_i}^{\frac 32}))$ it outputs a value of .66. It should be way larger than that. I think the issue is we integrated over a function to obtain "the area under the curve", but the results I'm looking for require that each segment has length 1 instead of the infinitesimal used by the integral. How do we change the function we integrate over to make it work?

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+sqrt%28n%2F6.25E34%29+from+1+to+6.25E34) gives $4.16667E34$ for the sum, which is an average value of $0.66$ over the length and [the same](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28n%2F6.25E34%29+from+1+to+6.25E34) for the integral

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea Alpha could do that. I'll give the equation a try. One question, Alpha also gave this value + 1.01832×10^-34 I, what is that?

Comment: It is a tiny imaginary part that crept in because of the way Alpha calculated it.